# How to properly apply the palette colors to my android project?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I am really interested in making my app meet the new material.io guidelines. While going trough the docs of material.io, i wanted to try the palette on my app. The palette creates a primary and secondary color and also the light and dark descendant colors. Now this confuses me: When I want to use these colors with my android material app, I came across the fact that android styles, including the `com.google.android.material` library, only accept a few colors for the apptheme:

```
<!--from android default:-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
<!-- added by the google material library:-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
```

Now as you can see, there only is the possibility to add the main palette colors, but mostly you can't add light or dark variants to your apptheme. How can I properly apply the guideline color system to my app, if the above seems not to meet the color system standards?

Answer (score 1):

The MDC Android library set the baseline material color theme: https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation

If you need additional color slots for your theme, you will have to create new attributes to represent those themed colors, and update styles on a component by component basis to use those new attributes.

You can see all the attributes that were added [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/values/attrs.xml) (Some attributes such as colorPrimary are used but they were already defined in AppCompat so they aren't redefined in that file)

Comment: I will have a look.